# javascript - display date as a string without padding of "01" if the date is only composed from year and month

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

***I am getting a date in some format*** *('yyyymmdd' or 'yyyymm')* and need to display it as a string in my current locale.

For this example, the locale is 'en-GB'.

When I get the full format(yyyymmdd), I am presetting dd/mm/yyyy, and if it is partial(yyyymm) I need to display mm/yyyy, but I get 01/mm/yyyy, how can I solve it?

this is my function-

```
getDateStrFromEsploro(date: string){
    if (date.length === 8){
        const year = date.substring(0,4);
        const month = date.substring(4,6);
        const day = date.substring(6);
        return DateUtils.getDateAsString(new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, parseInt(day)));
    } else if (date.length === 6){
        const year = date.substring(0,4);
        const month = date.substring(4,6);
        return DateUtils.getDateAsString(new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1));
    }
}
```

My DateUtils-

```
public static getDateAsString(date: Date) {
    return date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

Comment: *parseInt* is unnecessary in `new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month)-1, parseInt(day)`. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `toLocaleDateString()` options parameter

```js
// without options
console.log(new Date(2019, 7).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))

// with options
let date = new Date(2019, 7).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
});

console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the loop by checking the length

```js
const date1 = [2019, 8];
const date2 = [2019, 8, 7];
const dateString = (date) => new Date(...date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: date.length === 2 ? undefined : 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
});

console.log(dateString(date1));
console.log(dateString(date2));
```

Comment: In Safari, this returns *Invalid Date* for both dates. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). `new Date([2019, 8])` is not consistent with the formats supported by ECMA-262, nor are the arrays consistent with the OP's data.

Comment: @RobG Added destructuring to pass in the date. I see the OP parsed the date from the string using a custom function thus added this solution.